# Find Duplicate records where one field is different in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to find duplicate ticket_id where source column is different but ticket_id is same (see below picture which records are in red)

Here is the table structure

[image]

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT ticket_id, SOURCE, COUNT(ticket_id) AS NumOccurrences
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ticket_id, SOURCE
HAVING ( COUNT(ticket_id) > 1 )
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: @Igor I paste my code above which I have tried.

Comment: What about when you have 3 duplicate ticket_id values with 2 distinct sources (example: 2x apple and 1x tiger).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT d.Ticket_ID, COUNT(*)
FROM(
   SELECT DISTINCT Ticket_ID, Source
   FROM dups  
 ) d GROUP BY ticket_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you want the query to return the Ticket_ID and the Source, then you can do this:

```
SELECT a.* FROM dups a
JOIN( 
    SELECT d.Ticket_ID, count(*)
    FROM(
       SELECT distinct Ticket_ID, Source
       FROM dups  
     ) d GROUP BY ticket_id 
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) b on a.Ticket_ID = b.Ticket_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group on ticket_id and filter on only ones that have a distinct count of source greater than 1.

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM mytable 
   WHERE Ticket_ID IN (
        SELECT Ticket_ID
        FROM mytable
        GROUP BY Ticket_ID
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Source) > 1)
```

The above returns the actual rows. If you just need counts you could

```
SELECT Ticket_ID, COUNT(1)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Ticket_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT source) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your code also gives me records where duplicate ticket_id and duplicate source. Example, ticket_id is 4444 and source Apple. you see 5 and 6 row in picture above

Comment: I'm not sure what your mean, it wouldn't return 4444. See this demo of your example data http://rextester.com/XBHFN63204